# Prove that the lattice $(L, \leq)$ where $L = [0,1]$ is non algebraic lattice - only $0$ is compact element.

Tags: lattice-orders

I've already showed that $L$ is a complete lattice. I need to show it is non compactly generated, so not every element of $L$ is supremum of compact elements.

I see that only $0$ is compact element in that lattice, it's obvious, but how I should show that? Have no idea how do it properly.

I think that after showing this I just need to show $0$ is his own supremum and no other element of $L$ is supremum of compact elements. Am I right?

Waiting for any hints or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x \in (0, 1]$ we have that $x$ is the supremum of $[0, x)$. The latter is a directed set. However, even though we have $x \leq \sup [0, x)$, there is no element $y \in [0, x)$ such that $x \leq y$. This shows that $x$ is not compact. So no nonzero element is compact.

Of course, $0$ is trivially compact. Since a directed set $D \subseteq [0, 1]$ is non-empty by definition, there must be some $d \in D$ and we always have $0 \leq d$.

Comment: Okey, I get it, thanks a lot. I would just expand it that if we take some $y \in [0,y)$ which supremum is $y$ it is $x \leq y$ only if $x = y.$ Right?

I'm not sure I understand, why i can't use intervals $[0,x]$ instead of $[0,x)$?

Comment: @Kasia I am not entirely sure what your first sentence means, because $y \in [0, y)$ does not really make sense (or rather, is false). The reason I chose the interval $[0, x)$ is because for any $y \in [0, x)$ we have by definition that $y < x$ and so we cannot have $x \leq y$. You are right that $\sup [0, x]$ is also $x$, but that is not a counterexample to compactness because $x \in [0, x]$ and $x \leq x$.

Comment: @Kasia, you might also accept this answer (and maybe do the same to your other question, if you have a satisfying answer there). See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Of course, I mean we are taking an interval $[0,y)$ which $y$ is supremum of it and for any $a \in [0,x) sup{a} = sup{[0,y)}, $ for $y \leq x$ only if $x=y.$ I truly have no idea why I write it before this way, sorry. Thanks for explanation, everything is clear now.